# jquery-function doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a random generator and on another page if found a hint, that this would be easy using jQuery, so I tried the following.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>hello</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $ (document).ready(function() {
    $("body").load("hello.txt", function(msg) {
        var textArray = msg.split("\n");
    var zufall = Math.round ( ( textArray.length - 1 ) * ( Math.random() ) );
    });
   });
   document.write('<p>' + textArray[zufall] + '</p>');
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

it should work like this:
it loads a document with several lines of text ans splits it up at line break. this should be stored in an array and a random line should be displayed on the website.

My first idea was to write the text directly into an array but I thought loading it would be more efficient for the website.

Thanks for answering

PS: there isn't a error-message like "Error on this page" when the browser runs it.

**Final Edit**:

Thanks for helping!!! 
Now it works.

Here's the solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $ (document).ready(function() {
                 $.get("hello.txt", function(msg) {
                    var textArray = msg.split("\n");
            var zufall = Math.round ( ( textArray.length - 1 ) * ( Math.random() ) );

            $('body').append('<p>' + textArray[zufall] + '</p>');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't included the jquery file.

Comment: do you mean a line of code like this?
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes where ever is your jquery file
Some ting like this if you have the jquery.js file in the same directory:
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this alternate solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "hello.txt",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            textArray = data.split("\n");
            zufall = Math.round ( ( textArray.length - 1 ) * ( Math.random() ) );
             document.write('<p>' + textArray[zufall] + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

Also make sure you have included the jquery file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `document.write()` inside your `function(msg)` as AJAX is asynchronous and `load` is using AJAX, so `document.write()` doesn't wait until `load` is finished calling your anonymous function

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("hello.txt", function(msg) {
        var textArray = msg.split("\n");
        var zufall = Math.round ( ( textArray.length - 1 ) * ( Math.random() ) );
        $('body').append('<p>' + textArray[zufall] + '</p>');
    });
   });
```

EDIT:

I've just noticed you haven't included your jquery library o_O

Add the following above your `<script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should never use document.write inside a callback. If document.write is executed after the DOM has finished loading, it will overwrite the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

NiftyDude is right that you've put your document.write call outside the scope of your document.ready function. Also:

- It's also almost always a bad idea to use document.write. In this case you're waiting for an AJAX call to complete before using it, which means you're guaranteeing the document.write will overwrite the entire page body.
- You're using $('body').load, which is inappropriate in this case--you'll be adding text to the body manually.

Here's a fix:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>hello</title>
 </head>
 <body>>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("hello.txt", function(msg) {
        var textArray = msg.split("\n");
        var zufall = Math.round ( ( textArray.length - 1 ) * ( Math.random() ) );
        $('body').append('<p>' + textArray[zufall] + '</p>');
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints!!
It's also much faster now and works fine but now it prints the whole array first.

Comment: Sounds like you may not have replaced your $('body').load with $.get.